# Time conversion from 12-hour-format to 24-hour-format

Tags: c++

I have written this code:

```
string timeConversion(string s) {
    string time{s[0]}, twelveAM{"12"};
    time+=s[1];

    if((s.find("PM") != string::npos) || ((s.find("AM") != string::npos) && (time.compare(twelveAM)==0)))
        s.replace(s.begin(), s.begin()+2, to_string((stoi(time)+12)%24));

    s.replace(s.end()-2, s.end(), "");
    return s;
}
```

Here when `s` is `12:00:00AM` my output is `0:00:00` but it should be `00:00:00`.

Everything else is working fine, I'll appreciate any help given to solve this case.

Comment: Which part of your code did you expect to convert `12` to `00`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 s.replace( ...., to_string( here ) )

Comment: What is `to_string`?

Comment: std::setfill() and  std::setw() for string formatting.

Comment: ***What is to_string?*** [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: `to_string` doesn't do any formatting. I'd rather look into `strptime` and `strftime`.

Comment: `12:00:00AM`? I'm from a country where we use the 24h clock so I'm not sure, but that time does not exist, does it? If I understand it correctly, you have `00:00` (AM) and `12:00` (PM).

Comment: In the USA we use 12:00 AM (midnight). I have never heard anyone say 00:00 AM.

Comment: @drescherjm I understand that it may be different in spoken language. Do you also write 12:00 AM? I though 00:00 always meant AM and 12:00 always meant PM, when writing.

Comment: ***Do you also write 12:00 AM?*** Yes, never 00:00 AM.

Comment: @drescherjm I see. I was told to just write 00:00 and 12:00 and that adding AM/PM to those is redundant since 00:00 is AM and 12:00 is PM ... but ... I never really got it fully as you probably can tell :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to print: `cout << to_string((stoi(time)+12)%24) << endl;` you would see that you are only replacing the single 0:

```
if((s.find("PM") != string::npos) || ((s.find("AM") != string::npos) && (time.compare(twelveAM)==0))){
    cout << to_string((stoi(time)+12)%24) << endl;
    s.replace(s.begin(), s.begin()+2, to_string((stoi(time)+12)%24));
}
```

gives:

```
0
0:00:00
```

You should just add a second zero at the beginning, like: `s.replace(s.begin(), s.begin()+2, "00");`

Comment: I understand the problem! Thank you.

Comment: Language provide the functions for formatting here std::setfill and std::setw

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking into libraries like

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

or

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Both should have a conversion tool from your format into some other.

From my experience it's best to not write any date time code at all, even the simplest but use a library. One entertaining explanation for this can be found here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: I do it for the practice.

Comment: Writing your own date API?

Comment: I'm still newbie, maybe in the future :) still student.

Comment: Pro tip : learn to use libraries that solve your problem over reinventing the wheel. 1. Your solution will be buggy while existing solutions usually would pass 2. You can focus on new, more important problems than something that has been solved before.

Comment: I'll remember the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is code changes required if not interested in library functions:

```
std::stringstream string;
string << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (stoi(time) + 12) % 24);
s.replace(s.begin(), s.begin() + 2, string.str());
```